# Sheet name as variable to get last row from function

Tags: excel, vba

Can I pass a sheet name as a variable to a function to return the last row of the given sheet? If so, what would the structure of the code look like?  How would I pass the variable?  I'm using a simple function

```
Function lastRow()

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Function
```

and calling it here

```
Sub CopyResults()

'Copy DP-CustomerDates
DPCustomerDates.Range("A1:D" & lastRow).Copy
```

I find the last row multiple times on multiple sheets and origirnally created the function to avoid having the retype the whole with block over and over.  I'm revising my code base on some great information I've gotten from here and [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189567/building-a-new-excel-sheet-from-queries-on-existing-sheets/189623#189623) and I'm stuck on this new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the worsheet as a parameter:

```
Function lastrow(ws As Worksheet) As Long

    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Function
```

Then call it thus:

```
Sub CopyResults()

'Copy DP-CustomerDates
DPCustomerDates.Range("A1:D" & lastrow(DPCustomerDates)).Copy
End Sub
```

But if you are going to use that same number multiple times, instead of doing multiple calls, assign the return to a variable and call it only once.

```
Sub CopyResults()
Dim lstrw As Long
lstrw = lastrow (DPCustomerDates)
'Copy DP-CustomerDates
DPCustomerDates.Range("A1:D" & lstrw).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott but when I try assigning the return to a variable I get a compile error.  Expected function or variable. Sub CustomerData()

    Dim lRow As Long
    
    lRow = lastRow(CustomerData)

Comment: Make sure you did not declare `lastRow` somewhere in the sub that is calling the function.

Comment: I'm sure. What I did notice is that if I declare lrow as dim or public and outside of the sub I'm working in, it works.